# Remote SSH copy files with filenames that contain certain strings

Tags: linux, ssh, copy, remote-server, scp

I have two remote servers. One that I am currently connected to and one that I am trying to copy a lot of files to (10.10.0.13)

I have a series of files I need to copy within various directories of the format:

```
/opt/DR/output/1/a/csva1file.csv
/opt/DR/output/1/a/csva2file.csv
/opt/DR/output/1/b/csvb1file.csv
/opt/DR/output/1/b/csvb2file.csv
/opt/DR/output/1/b/csvb3file.csv
/opt/DR/output/1/b/csvb4file.csv
/opt/DR/output/1/c/csvc1file.csv
...
/opt/DR/output/30/a/csva1file.csv
```

And this continues for output/1 to output/40 folders. All the folders inside are identical and all the filenames inside will all contain similar strings, just with slight differences depending on the folder they are in.

I want to copy **all** the files that contain "a1" from any directory to a folder in a remote server:

```
root@10.10.0.13:/data/landing/a/a1/
```

Similarly, I want to do this for all b1, c1, c2 etc. files and copy them to their respective places on the remote server.

I cannot seem to find a way to do this that doesn't involve writing multiple lines of code.

I have tried

```
cd /opt/DR/output/1/a/
scp -r -v *a1* root@10.10.0.13:/data/landing/a/a1/
```

which works but I want to copy **ALL* the a1 csv files rather than having to do them one by one.

I have looked into globbing but don't think it can be used for my case. I have also looked at using paramiko/glob for python but I couldn't get that to work either. 
Ideally, I would like to do this with a bash shell script, but a python script would also work.

Hope this makes sense. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can copy via SFTP or SCP.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: This seems like it should work. What does it do instead?

Comment: @Barmar it does work, but requires me to do all the file copies individually, rather that in bulk.

Comment: You only have one `a1` file in `output/1/a`. What other files should it transfer?

Comment: You should put a wildcard in the directory name, not cd into a specific subdirectory.

Comment: `/opt/DR/output/*/a/*a1*`

Comment: But you have the same filename `csva1file.csv` in multiple directories. You can't copy them all to the same directory on the destination.

Comment: Do you want to preserve directory structure on remote server or all files from one group land in one folder (it assumes no name clash in input file names)?